# VM Limit in Android 2.0

Tags: android

Is there a way to expand the VM limit in Android 2.0 on an actual device?  Using `java.lang.Runtime.maxMem()` on a Droid reveals a limit of 24MB, and I've written some code that incrementally allocates memory until failure to verify that figure.  You can set the VM size in the emulator, but I haven't yet found a way to do that for a connected phone.  Is there some type of a properties file on the device itself that can be modified?