# Video memory and android applications

Tags: android, memory, video, opengl-es, limit

I would like to know if the video memory (VRAM) that an android OpenGL application can use is limited ? If so, would you know what the limit is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limit depends on how much the device has. On many devices, the VRAM is actually part of the general purpose RAM. I don't think there is a way to find how much there is at runtime. The total RAM on current devices will vary between about 256 MB and up. However, you may have problems allocating more than a certain limit (16MB, 24MB, 28MB etc.) that is fixed per device. See [VM Limit in Android 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1785406/vm-limit-in-android-2-0) for details.

Answer (score 0):

The OpenGL driver allocates normal RAM until you run out of it and normal RAM size is device independent.